# How to view Hidden Files in Finder?

Tags: finder, file

I have some .m2 files which I need to copy from Finder in Mac but I don't see them there. How can I see the hidden files in Finder.

One workaround is to open the folder in terminal and use ls -a command to list all files but I am  looking for a way to view in Finder.

Answer (score 1):

To make the hidden files on your Mac visible, you can do so by following these steps:

1. In Finder, open up your Macintosh HD folder
2. Press Command+Shift+Dot
3. Your hidden files will become visible. Repeat step 2 to hide them again!

This process will also work elsewhere, including your Documents or Applications folders.

You can find other options as well like commond line option at the below link : https://setapp.com/how-to/show-hidden-files-on-mac